# add auto increment value to li element using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html-lists, element, auto-increment

I have the following code that its been dynamically generated by a plugin, the plugin will create a "li" element for each team member, currently i have 150 members so it needs to add an auto increment ID.  Thanks!

```
<ul id="dvteamgrid<?php echo esc_attr($random); ?>" class="dvteamgrid withanim">
<li data-filter-class='["gridall",<?php echo $filters; ?>]'>
    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($thumb_url); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"/>
</li>
```

This is how the html code looks like:

```
<ul id="dvteamgrid225306813" class="dvteamgrid withanim">
  <li data-filter-class="["gridall","dvfilter5997", "dvfilter6007", "dvfilter6025";]">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Abee-C.jpg">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I meant "add auto increment ID to li element using jQuery" on title.

Comment: you can do that in php itself.

Comment: Ok that should work too. Can you show me how? Thanks

Comment: I am a dotnet developer so I cannot help you with php code. but wherever you're looping to create those `li` elements, thats where you need to add the auto incremented value

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through each `li` element and attach the auto incremented id.

```
var auto_inc_id = 0; //initialise value of auto incremented id to 0
$('ul.dvteamgrid li').each(function(){ //loop through each list element of ul
    $(this).attr('id', auto_inc_id); //attach to current li an id attribute that has auto_inc_id as its value
    auto_inc_id++; //increment auto_inc_id by one
});
```